# Disable U+00A0 no-break space (custom keyboard setting)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, eclipse, utf-8

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Mac and use Eclipse and EiffelStudio for programming. My keyboard layout is set to "German (Switzerland, Macintosh)" which I would like to keep because I'm familiar with the shortcuts of this layout. My problem is that I am sometimes getting the compilation error

```
    stray '\240' in program
    stray '\302' in program
```

which happens after I accidentally pressed SHIFT+Space (instead of Space only). This produces a no-break space which can not be interpreted. Removing this space and adding one again solves the problem, but this becomes tedious after some time. I tried the keyboard layout "German (Macintosh, eliminate dead keys)" where I did not have the problem, but I would actually prefer to work with my current keyboard layout.

Where can I adjust my current keyboard layout settings such that SHIFT+space does not result in a no-break space but just a normal space instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard (point "Disabling non-breaking space"). In the ~/.Xmodmap file, I had to change keycode 65 to

```
keycode 65 = space space
```

and after applying the changes with

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

it worked as i wanted (I had also to put this last command into my .bashrc file to make the changes permanent).